# SQL Query to SUM data from 3 different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have 3 SQL Server 2005 tables, an `order` table, `quote` table and `invoice` table, structured like this:

**SO** table

```
Rep Code SO Amount SO Date
----------------------------
1         100     1/2/2015
2          50     2/15/2015
3          20     2/20/2015
2          50     2/20/2015
1          85     2/20/2015
```

**SQ** table

```
Rep Code SQ Amount SQ Date
---------------------------
1        50        2/2/2015
2        14        2/18/2015
3        67        2/19/2015
1        96        2/20/2015
2        54        2/20/2015
```

**INV** table

```
Rep Code INV Amount INV Date
-----------------------------
1         654      2/2/2015
2         312      2/18/2015
3          54      2/19/2015
1           6      2/20/2015
3          48      2/20/2015
```

What I want to do is write a query which will sum up each amount by rep code, so it would look something like this:

```
Rep Code SO Total SQ Total Inv Total
------------------------------------    
1        185      146      660
2        100       68      312
3        20        67      102
```

I would also like it to only pull the totals if the appropriate date for each one is lets say in the last week. (So Today -7)

Let me know if this needs any clarification.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Do you have a 4th table that includes all possible `Rep Code` values?

Comment: PM77 there isn't currently a table with all possible Rep Code values but I could create one.  Marc I was able to SUM  the amounts in the SO table but I wasn't sure how to then also sum the amounts in the other two tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with FULL JOINs:

```
DECLARE @start_date DATE = '20150101', @end_date DATE = '20150223'

    SELECT  t.RepCode ,
    SUM(SoAmount) AS SoAmount ,
    SUM(SqAmount) AS SqAmount ,
    SUM(InvAmount) AS InvAmount
    FROM ( 
        SELECT  COALESCE(so.RepCode, sq.RepCode, inv.RepCode) AS RepCode ,
        ISNULL(so.SoAmount, 0) AS SoAmount ,
        ISNULL(sq.SqAmount, 0) AS SqAmount ,
        ISNULL(inv.InvAmount, 0) AS InvAmount
        FROM    ( SELECT    RepCode ,
                    SUM(SoAmount) AS SoAmount
          FROM      SO
          WHERE     SoDate >= @start_date
                    AND SoDate <= @end_date
          GROUP BY  RepCode
        ) so
        FULL JOIN ( SELECT  RepCode ,
                            SUM(SqAmount) AS SqAmount
                    FROM    SQ
                    WHERE   SqDate >= @start_date
                            AND SqDate <= @end_date
                    GROUP BY RepCode
                  ) sq ON so.RepCode = sq.RepCode
        FULL JOIN ( SELECT  RepCode ,
                            SUM(InvAmount) AS InvAmount
                    FROM    INV
                    WHERE   InvDate >= @start_date
                            AND InvDate <= @end_date
                    GROUP BY RepCode
                  ) inv ON inv.RepCode = sq.RepCode     
    ) t
    GROUP BY t.RepCode
```